# Examples of maintaining memory with database connections for VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a particular problem in database connection disposal and despite there being a lot of back and forth over disposal of connections, datasets, and datatables I can't quite wrap my head around it as a new VB coder. My project has a form with a simple "Import Database" button which opens a connection. Lets assume I have a database with several Datasets and datatables that take up a bunch of memory so I have to be careful how I open and close things. I have a button to close the database when done with it. The code briefly looks like this and does not throw me errors (i.e. I can connect, get the right data and then close the database without an error being thrown)

```
Public ConnectedDB as DataBaseOps

Class Form1
  Private Sub ImportDatabaseButton(sender as object, e and eventargs) handles ImportDatabasebutton.click
    'Open filedialog and return the path, etc.
    strPATH = OpenFileDialogMaster(...my filters here...)
    ConnectedDB.OpenDatabase(strPath)
  End Sub

  Private Sub populateDSDT(....)
    '...populate my datasets which then populate my datagrids
    ConnectedDB.PopulateMyDataSet()
    '...populate my datagrids
  End sub

  Private Sub CloseDatabaseButton(sender as object, e and eventargs) handles CloseDatabaseButton.click
    ConnectedDB.CloseDatabase()
    'Can I put something here to clean up the DatabaseOPs class?
  End Sub
End Class
```

Now in a separate class

```
Private Class DataBaseOps
Public OpenCon As OleDb.OleDbConnection

  Public Sub OpenDataBase(strPath as String)
    'My.Settings.ConnectionString is a variable in App.Config
    OpenCon = New OleDb.OleDbConnection(My.Settings.ConnectionString & strPath)
    OpenCon.Open()
  End Sub

  Public Sub PopulateMyDataSet()
    '...Populate my datasets and tables based on data from the database
'...Note that for the adapters I include "Using" to help keep those clean when I no longer need them
  End sub 

  Public Sub CloseDatabase()
        Try
            OpenCon.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("No Database file loaded.")
        End Try
  End Sub

  Overrides Sub Finalize()
    '...Datasets get .Dispose() which is a topic of its own elsewhere.
    OpenCon.Dispose()
  End Sub
End Class
```

Keep in mind there are other ways of doing this but the key factor here is to open the connection, keep it open to populate datagrids, do some other work in the database, and then close it releasing the connection and datasets memory.

My problem is I've tried various means to limit the scope of "ConnectedDB" and its datasets including putting a Finalize() sub into the process in an attempt to remove it from memory. I also toyed with scoping but neither of these ideas work perfectly and it seems to retain items in memory.
Using my general code what can I do to clean up the memory resource here? As a relatively new VB.net coder, am I missing something obvious (like I could maybe inherit one class to the other instead of calling them?)

Comment: Remove this: `Public OpenCon As OleDb.OleDbConnection`. When you need to open a connection, do it in-place. With a `Using` statement, possibly, otherwise `.Dispose()` it and dispose of all the other disposable objects you have created. The  connection pool is managed.

Comment: If I understand you, I originally thought of this when I was designing the code. Just turn the connection on/off as I need. However there are a number of operations that need it open (expanding its life cycle) and so I eventually just opted to keep it open to keep it simple for procedures to do their job and then close it out when the user is done with it.

Comment: The *life-cycle* of a connection is managed elsewhere. Don't try to override that logic. You don't need to try and keep a Connection *open*. When the code needs a connection, it just *asks to provide one* (your code doesn't *create* connections, it receives one form the Pool, which manages the life of its managed objects). You may use a method that creates a new Connection object, returns the object and handles its destruction **as soon as** the method that requested it has performed its tasks (just to D.R.Y. up your code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep your connections local to where they are used. Then you can use Using...End Using blocks to ensure that they are closed and disposed.

Thanks to Duncan Edwards Jones for this quote.

> "A database connection is like a refrigerator door - You only open it
>   when you need something, you only take out what you need, and you
>   close it as soon as you have taken out what you need. "

A DataSet can hold more than one DataTable. I am not sure why you would need more than one DataSet.

```
Class Form1
    Private ConnectedDB As DataBaseOps
    Private ds As DataSet
    Private Sub ImportDatabaseButton(sender As Object, e And eventargs) Handles ImportDatabaseButton.click
        Dim OpenDial As New OpenFileDialog
        'Open filedialog and return the path, etc.
        Dim strPATH = OpenDial.FileName
        ConnectedDB = New DataBaseOps(strPATH)
    End Sub

    Private Sub populateDSDT()
        '...populate my datasets which then populate my datagrids
        ds = ConnectedDB.PopulateMyDataSet()
        '...populate my datagrids
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class DataBaseOps

    Private DBFile As String
    Public Sub New(file As String)
        DBFile = file
    End Sub

    Public Function PopulateMyDataSet() As DataSet
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Using OpenCon As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(My.Settings.ConnectionString & DBFile)
            OpenCon.Open() 'But don't do this until directly before the .Execute...
            '...Populate my datasets and tables based on data from the database
            '...Note that for the adapters I include "Using" to help keep those clean when I no longer need them
        End Using
        Return ds
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: I only really have two datasets and that's only to keep two separate sides to my data (raw vs. cooked). I could put them all in a single set but I kept them separate for the poor reviewer behind me. Now this wasn't part of my question but both you and Jimi have suggested using the connection only as long as I need it. What happens then when I start working with the database in SQL land? I have ~40 queries lined up that fire off either in blocks or all together so that was why I was thinking to just keep my "refrigerator door" open as I rearrange my data.

Comment: Having thought about this, I think Mary and Jimi have the best overall answers to this particular question and that is to keep the connection open/shut as I need it. This poses further, different questions about the best possible way to move blocks of data around connections but that is another question for another topic which I'll link to in my main question when I get time to write it. Thanks both for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Add this two lines in your Finalize method after `OpenCon.Dispose()`

```
GC.Collect()
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```